# Where is this toolbar coming from in iOS

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I'm working with a webview, the current page has a form on it, and it seems that this toolbar is popping up at the bottom to let me switch between the different text fields in this view.  What I can't figure out is what to even call this toolbar to see if there's a method to hide it.

[image]

So basically, what is this toolbar, and how do I block it from coming up over my webview

Comment: It comes from the textfield that has focus and usually in on top of the keyboard, which might be hidden on a device paired with a bluetooh keyboard or on de simulator.

And to my knownledge you can not hide it.

Comment: But there's no keyboard, and I don't have a bluetooth keyboard hooked up to the device.  Also, I didn't click on the field.  This is the simulator though, so interesting point.  Let me flip to actual phone and see.  Since it's simulator it's possible hiding the keyboard in which case that's fine.

Comment: that is an accessory-view for the keyboard what you have turned off on your simulator.

Comment: On a simulator if you can press cmd+K to toggle the keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is in the comments.  Looks like that was just the keyboard in the simulator popping up and I hadn't noticed before the simulator acts like a bluetooth keyboard here.  I thought my view changes had caused it.